# Статический метод class laravel - для чего он?

Tags: php, laravel

Для чего нужен и что выводит метод ::class laravel и почему вызывается без аргументов и скобок?

```
PhotoController::class;
```

Comment: это не laravel, а php - http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: Понятно,спасибо!с наступающим!

Comment: @n.osennij это вовсе не константы, а получение полного имени класса с пространством имен.

Comment: @Alexxosipov То есть в мануале чушь написана да?

Comment: @u_mulder в мануале написано про константы. Где вы видите в конструкции `::class` константу? Попробуйте инициализировать константу `const class`, посмотрим, что php вам на это скажет. Можно сюда вообще ссылку про ООП скинуть, но смысл-то один - ссылка нерелевантна

Comment: Если открыть мануал, то сможете прочесть что class это специальная константа, хранящая FQCN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру, у нас есть какая-либо функция, которая принимает на входе массив классов и вызывает у каждого из класса метод `init()`:

```
Class First {
  public function init() 
  {
    echo 'Method init in first class was called';
  }
}  
Class Second {
  public function init() 
  {
    echo 'Method init in second class was called';
  }
} 

$classes = [
  First::class,
  Second::class
];

foreach ($classes as $class) {
  $classObject = new $class();
  if (method_exists($classObject, 'init')) {
    $classObject->init();
  }
}
```

Во-первых, этим мы избавляемся от написания полного пути для класса. К примеру, представим, что класс `Second` лежит в пространстве имен `App`, тогда, если бы мы писали массив `$classes` строками, нам бы пришлось использовать следующее:

```
$classes = [
  'Fisrt',
  'App\Second'
]
```

Однако, использовав конструкцию `::class`, мы можем использовать полное название класса (с пространством имен) в конструкции `Use`, а в массив занести только сам класс:

```
Use App\Second;

$classes = [
  First::class,
  Second::class
];
```

Тем самым мы избавляемся от написания полного пространства имен. На моём примере польза не очень заметна, но когда пространство имен состоит из 3 и более дочерних пространств имен, код становится гораздо чище.

Comment: А возвращает путь до файла или только название?

Comment: @ArturHan возвращает полное имя класса. Это не путь до файла, поскольку (хоть и надеюсь, что такое только в учебных примерах увижу) в 1 файле может быть несколько неймспейсов, которые, в свою очередь, будут вложены друг в друга. Посмотрите на мой пример, тут всего 1 файл, при этом класс `Second` находится в неймспейсе `App`